# access 2013 report of record counts

Tags: database, report, ms-access-2013

Is it possible to create a report in Access 2013 that simply shows the record count of selected queries?  For example, if I have the following queries:

- query a
- query b
- query c

I want a saved report that will update each time I run it and show the following - where "xx" is the number of records specific to each individual query:

query a has xx records
query b has xx records
query c has xx records

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Create three textboxes on the report with *ControlSources* like:

```
=DCount("*", "Query1")
=DCount("*", "Query2")
=DCount("*", "Query3")
```